# plank cli always shows http://plnkr.co/edit/undefined?p=preview

Tags: command-line-interface, node-modules

I am on Mac.
I have done these steps:

- Install the package globally
- authorize the package following the instructions
- run plunk
- My node version is: v7.6.0

There is already an issue open [here](https://github.com/iliakan/plunk/issues/15), to draw wider attention I am posting it on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

For valid codes there are no issues.
The codes which are breaking the cli are the codes which doesn't save successfully on plunker.
ie which throws `400 (Bad Request)` on pressing the save button at plunkr

[image: screen shot 2017-05-22 at 10 35 09 am]